# How to find EOL (end of line) in a byte-stream from a serial device

Tags: python, pyserial

I try to read lines from a device that sends every 2 seconds 1 to 3 lines of text to a serial printer, using pyserial to read the serial output of that device.

First, I have used minicom to get an output-sample: When I open it with a hax-reader (ghex in linux), I see that every end of line has the hex-value x0A.

When I capture the output with pyserial (version 3.2.1) byte by byte:

```
print(self.ser.read())
```

the output at the end of a line is

b'\r'

b'\n'

every time a line ends (why two characters?)

I have tried to define a read_line() function:

```
import serial  

def read_line(self):
        line = []
        print("start read_line")
        while True:
            print("read_line_loop")
            for c in self.ser.read():
                line.append(c)
                print("appended")
                if c == b'\x0A':
                    print("stop condition")
                    print("Line: " + line)
                    line = []
                    break
```

The loop is enterd as expected, but the condition c == b'\x0A' is never met.
The messages shown are "read_line_loop", and every to seconds several times
"appended", but never "stop condition".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ending a line with \r\n (carriage return, line feed) is the normal Windows (and typewriter) method to end a line. Translated in Hex these signs are '\x0D' and '\x0A'. Why it is not found I cannot tell you. But as you are reading lines, I would use the readline method of the serial port. As your line is ending with \n it should work nicely. You only get a problem, when your line is not ending with \n, but with something else.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to output c to see what it actually is. c is likely something different than what you think.

Another approach could be to use the built-in readline method, which uses newline as it de(http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline).

Comment: The eol parameter for readline() is no longer supported when pySerial is run with newer Python versions (V2.6+) where the module io is available.
(your link)

Comment: @ StackUMan In fact, print(c) hangs, print(str(c)) shows dezimal numbers of the caracter ("10" for \x0A, "32" for \x20 etc). So, the stop-codition works with:

`if str(c) == "10":`

Its helpful, but confusing, since the line-array contains something like Line: [50, 52, 45, 7, 10] instead of a string...